# Webview screen shows nothing

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I have a topic.

I have a webview in my ionic app, it works all the pages that use https I understand. But when I use this link: https://portal.argos.com.do/, because the screen goes blank and says nothing else. That happens when I use it as _self. Anyone know why?

Code:

```ts
openurl(url: string) {
    const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      zoom: 'no'
    };    
    const bro = this.browser.create(url, '_self', options);
}
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
          android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1"
          package="io.ionic.starter"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" 
                      android:largeScreens="true" 
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:resizeable="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application 
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" 
            android:supportsRtl="true" 
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
                  android:label="@string/activity_name"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the page even if it says https is not completely secure, because the server uses a TLS 1.0 and not the updated ones now. You can find some pages that verify your SSL certificate just in case:

https://www.dondomain.com/products/ssl/tools/ssl-checker/

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Then the solution would be to ignore the SSL of the page.

Also a way to test and know more in depth is (in my case) with android studio see the emulator log of my application and use this code to ignore the SSL and know what is the cause it has here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49786820/11150506

So in ionic what should be done is to ignore the SSL and the page will be displayed, but the play store may not allow it, so it should create a way for the user to cancel the action of going to the page Not sure yes or no.

It is the same here:
[Webview: Failed to validate the certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120633/webview-failed-to-validate-the-certificate-chain/49786820) (android java)