# Is a SSL certificate still needed in a Flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, webview, ssl-certificate, android-webview

We currently have an Angular web app created for an online ordering utility.
But we want to create a native app out of it, and we wanted to use Flutter.

At first, though we just want to use a webview to show the existing Angular app through there.

The problem is, we wanted to do this because we also wanted to get rid of the need for an SSL certificate to access the app through a phone.

Is it still necessary to have an SSL certificate for a webview?

I imagine it is because it's still like accessing the webpage afterall, but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there is no option to bypass/ignore/proceed without SSL in [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and the [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) has been almost deprecated and not updated for the last 2 years till this answer.
but there is a solution available in [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter).

It is recommended to use HTTPS calls only in Apps. Transport security was introduced in iOS 9.0, allowing only HTTPS calls from apps by default.

However, if you still want to allow all non-https calls - Add NSAppTransportSecurity (Dictionary) in Info.plist and Add a Subkey named NSAllowsArbitraryLoads with the boolean value YES. After the update, plist should look like

Method 1: In source code of info.plist file we can add that:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Method 2: Or you can do it in Xcode

1. Opened my Project target's info.plist file
2. Added a Key called NSAppTransportSecurity as a Dictionary.
3. Added a Subkey called NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as Boolean and set its
   value to YES as in the following image.

[image]

Comment: I am marking this as the accepted answer since it is a more updated one. Thank you so much :)!

Answer (score 9):

The `webview_flutter` plugin hasn't any option to ignore SSL errors.
Instead, using my [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin, it is very simple to ignore SSL errors as you would normally do on Android, that is using the `onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest` event and returning `ServerTrustAuthResponse(action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);` for the specified request or for all requests.

A simple example using the latest version [`5.0.5+3`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/5.0.5+3) and https://badssl.com/ (that is a site for testing clients against bad SSL configs, see https://github.com/chromium/badssl.com) is:

```dart
child: InAppWebView(
  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
      url: Uri.parse("https://self-signed.badssl.com/")
  ),
  onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest: (controller, challenge) async {
    print(challenge);
    return ServerTrustAuthResponse(action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);
  },
),
```

where the `challenge` argument provides all the information about the challenge, such as host, protocol, realm, etc.

Also, on Android, when you return the action to be taken (`PROCEED` or `CANCEL`), this decision is saved by Android itself, so the next time you go to the same URL, the `onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest` event won't be triggered.
In that case, you can use the `controller.android.clearSslPreferences()` method to clear the Android SSL preferences.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply!! I'll try it out also and if I see it adapts better, I'll mark this as the answer. :)

Comment: Is it possible to show other widgets (like snackbars or buttons) above your plugin? With [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) you can't AFAIK, and we might not use that feature right now, but it would be really interesting for the future!

Comment: Just check the documentation! Yes, you can use `InAppWebView` widget, that is, well, a flutter widget :)

Comment: Nice, thank you so much! The documentation is wonderful, I'll dive right into it. ^_^

Comment: I tried this and its works completely fine with Android, but in IOS its not happening.

Comment: Same for me, works on Android but not on iOS

Answer (score 2):

[webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package has no option to disable SSL checks and ignore SSL errors. It is an official Flutter plugin and they don't want to provide an ability to make untrusted connections with https. Here is related [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36925) on github.

However you can use non-official plugins for webview that provide such capability. E.g. [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin):

```
final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(
    'your-url.com',
    ignoreSSLErrors: true,
);
```