# handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 - Flutter WebView

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have "https" url and i get this error when i try to view the link with WebView.

E/chromium(13842): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202

Comment: What happens if you open the same URL on Chrome app on the same device?

Comment: To ignore SSL errors, you can use my [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin using the `onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest` event! Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66441167/4637638) for an example.