invalid certificate in Android flutter inappwebview
Android error：
E/chromium( 2463): [ERROR:aw_contents_client_bridge.cc(257)] No client certificate selected
But the same HTTPS URL is valid in iOS
enter image description here
But it is not working.
Can I get any suggestions for solving the error?
Thanks!

could you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420760/is-a-ssl-certificate-still-needed-in-a-flutter-webview?

@chunhunghan Thank you for your reply, But this is bidirectional authentication, This is client request error. Response code : 400. So unusable onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest
